# replace "2999/12/31" value with "" before printing Formal report (Jasperserver)

Tags: jasperserver

What I want to do is intercept each variable before being printed to a Formal report and check if it is "2999/12/31" and if so it must print blank

I have already done this for AdHoc views but they work different to The Formal reports created in iReport

Here is how my Ad Hoc reports now print

[image]
Note That in the "cde_enddate" the values print as "" but are actually "2999/12/31"

I did this by adding a if statement to tableRows.jsp

My question is where can I intercept values printing to formal reports to accomplish this same thing ?

Comment: I know you can use the Print when parameter on fields in iReport but we are looking for a generic change since we don't want to go edit every singe report we have previously created.

Answer (score 0):

For achieving this you could simply make use of Ternary expression as the expression for the text field.

For instance-

$F{cde_enddate).equals("2999/12/31")
? ""
:$F{cde_enddate)

Hope that this helps

Comment: I know you can use the Print when parameter on fields in iReport but we are looking for a generic change since we don't want to go edit every singe report we have previously created. And this solution won't work for Ad Hoc generated reports